# Python SSL client certificate

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to use client side certificates for authentication in Python, but I just can't figure it out.

I am using this for my testing:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-client-auth/
(Skip to "TLS Client Authentication On The Edge" for the pem file and example curl call).

It works as expected in curl, but when I try it in Python I get a 403 back from the server.

Here is what I have tried in Python:

```
import ssl
import socket
s = socket.socket()
addr_info = socket.getaddrinfo('auth.pizza',443)
addr = addr_info[0][-1]
ss = ssl.wrap_socket(s, certfile='pizza.pem')
ss.connect(addr)
ss.write(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
print(ss.read(4096))
```

I'm at a loss for how to even debug this further.